# You slept well AT night or IN night?

Tags: prepositions

When talking to my friend who tells me that he's sleepy, I want to tell him that I hope that he slept good at /in (last) night. What is the correct way to say it?

> 1) I hope you slept well **at** night.
>
> 2) I hope you slept well **in** night.
>
> 3) I hope you slept well **at** the last night.
>
> 4) I hope you slept well **in** the last night.

Comment: You slept well last night/in the night/during th night. You cannot say "at night". You use this phrase when you are talking  about something that happens regularly every night.

Answer (score -1):

None of the mentioned alternative, that's how you should say:

> I hope you slept well last night

When using last night, which is a period of time, no preposition is necessary, at/on/in, none of them will be used before last night, and it also works for others periods of time: last month, last day, last week..

Others examples:

> I hope you did well in the job interview last week
>
> I hope he gave you the present I made for you last month
>
> I hope you looked after my son as I was out last hour

As you can see, no preposition is used before a period of time that includes the word "last".

And if you are talking this night, it doesn't take preposition too, see: I hope you slept well this night. = *This night* = *today's night*

You are only allowed to use prepositions in that sentence if you are talking about a night, not a specific one, from which a period of time hasn't been mentioned, see: I hope you sleep good at night/morning/evening.

> The night in here is very cold, I hope you sleep well at night.
>
> The morning here is very hot, I hope you can sleep well at morning.
>
> John and Peter can't sleep at night because the night is cold, I hope they get used to this.

Thanks for *Araucaria* for pointing out some mistakes.

Comment: "last day" and "last morning" were just to emphasize my answer, buddy, but I'm almost sure no one is going to use this term, these were the only examples I could think of, lol, yesterday sounds much better, and by saying _at nights_ I referred to night in plural, all nights, not only one, but thank you for your comment, if I think about any better example, I will ensure to add them into my answer

Comment: "... as I was out last hour" isn't British English. You could say "... as I was out for the last hour" or "...while I was out for the last hour" or ".. as I have been out for the last hour".

Comment: I have already edited the answer and replaced the "in the" by the "at" although I have made some researches which comproved that "in the nights" is also acceptable, but anyway, that's fine.

I don't see any need to replace the "as I was out", it's used in American English, I only gave the British word definition of until because it's a general term.

Comment: No, Araucaria, I will just increase some notes in order to warn the OP that those were only examples and must not be used in real sentences, if you think of any better example, send me here so that I can increase them into my answer

Comment: Araucaria, my post has no grammatical mistakes, last morning or last day aren't only used because the term "yesterday" is more proper. I have made some researches and found out that in the night may also be used, "in the night" means late, from 9:00 forward, "in the night" may be used. If you wish to see some sources, I'll be glad to send you some :)

Comment: What kind of articles are you talking about? please, quote some examples so I can get your point. Last day and last morning were only to emphasize my examples. Please, check out the note I have increased into my answer

Comment: I just wanted to reinforce @Araucaria's message. You cannot simply use *last day* as a direct substitute for *yesterday*. It's incorrect. Nobody says it. You *can* use it with articles (*a*, *an*, *the*) and prepositions to construct more complex phrases. ("Over the last day, I received fifty-five separate phone calls.")

Comment: Even though I agree with @Araucaria that it looks much better now, I still don't like your attempt at generalizing the usage and boiling it down to this rule much: "You are only allowed to use prepositions in that sentence if you are talking about night in general, when no particular night has been specified." -- It's not exactly wrong, but strictly speaking, it's wrong, and thus, it's a bit misleading. Here is a counter-example: *I hope you slept well during that night*.

Comment: @Damkerng T I didn't post it, someone edited my post and changed almost everything in my answer, what's that for? Did any moderador approve that change? I will put it back exactly as I wrote it, no need to send an edit request about my answer.

Comment: Truth be told though, you did fix the errors *after* they had been pointed out to you in the edits. It's not as if the edits introduced grammatical or idiomatic errors. P.S. After prepositions the gerund is used, e.g. "Many thanks to Araucaria **for** *pointing out* the..." or "... for *pointing out* **to** me the ...."

Comment: Your rollback of my edit has reintroduced some errors: *at morning* should be *in the morning*, *last hour* should be *an hour ago* (or perhaps *in the last hour*), and *last day* **cannot** be used in the same way as *last week* or *last month*; it should be *yesterday* **unless** you are constructing a more complex phrase ("In the last day", "the last day of school", etc.).

Comment: Also, I believe that my edit was entirely appropriate and in keeping with the purpose of the site. Please see this section of the help pages: "Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: Sorry to keep piling on like this, but if you want to set a good example, you should correct some mistakes in your opening sentence. 1) The first part has no clear meaning. You specify a number of "alternatives" (zero), but then you don't say anything *about* them. It should be something like "None of the mentioned alternatives *are correct*", or "*You should use* none of the mentioned alternatives". 2) "alternatives" needs to be plural. 3) "that's", as you use it, points to an item that is far away, but your example follows immediately. Use "this is" or "here's". 4) End with "say *it*:".

Comment: Davyd I understand it can be uncomfortable having people correct what you've written, but it is an important part of how this site works. Most folks are just trying to help your answer be as good as it can be, however, if you feel someone is acting in bad faith you can raise a flag for the mod team and we will look into it.

Comment: @ColleenV I have a question in general, why are people allowed to edit any post without even putting the right informations? Are the edits requests at least analyzed by any moderador before being applied? Someone edited my answer and basically rewrote everything I had written. I appreciate any good suggestion that could be helpful for the OP, but I admit I have skipped some critics from some very ignorant and rude users, that is very uncomfortable, having someone to correct me is great.

Comment: Thank you, Colleen. Someone eddited my answer unecessarily and rewrote all what I had written. I found it totally unecessary, if someone wanted to write a new and completely different answer, shouldn't they have written their own answers? These kind of edits should not be approved. Anyway, I fixed all the examples and increased the details provided by some users, and I understand we do it for the best, I bear in mind that others users may also have the same question and will probably find posts like this.

Comment: Users with a [certain amount of reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) can edit without needing approval and approve suggested edits. This site is moderated by the whole community, which is very different from the way other sites work and takes some getting used to. If you feel someone has gone too far, you can always roll back to an earlier version, but I would strongly encourage you to look at the changes they made with an open mind and see if maybe some of them could make your answer better.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit, but this answer still does not sound like idiomatic AmE to me. Maybe it's idiomatic BrE, but in that case it should be indicated as such. Aside from the comma splices that are driving me crazy, there are phrases such as "at morning" and "at evening" that I have never heard.

Comment: I'm voting to ***delete*** this post, otherwise we'll be here forever correcting mistakes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good! I don't have voting privileges on here, but it's definitely what needs to be done.

Comment: @Araucaria: I cast my vote *before* reading the comments. It's obvious the OP (the guy who wrote the answer, not the question) did genuinely try to engage with people pointing (or *editing*) out mistakes, but imho there are simply too many. Plus I don't buy OP's generalisation about prepositions and *specific* nights/evenings/etc., *and* I don't think it's really appropriate to use an Answer as a "personal classroom" for one poster. I'm okay with correcting the odd *slip-up*, but when the answerer doesn't necessarily *recognise* what's wrong, that just means something's gone *really* wrong.